# Que signifie l'expression « bien mal m'en aura pris » ?

Tags: expressions, sens

Je ne suis pas sûr de l'exactitude de l'expression.
Peut-être dit-on « mal m'en aura pris » ?

Je la trouve souvent et j'ai seulement une vague idée de sa signification exacte.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

L'Académie indique à l'entrée du verbe [*prendre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/Prendre) (9<sup>e</sup> édition):

> Par extension, se manifester, surgir soudainement chez quelqu'un. [...]
>       Dans des formules indiquant la satisfaction ou le regret. 
>       *J'ai dit non, et bien m'en a pris. Mal lui en a pris d'être aussi curieux.*

La formule *bien m'en a pris* veut donc dire que la chose entreprise était bonne. En revanche, *mal m'en a pris* veut dire que cela a eu de fâcheuses conséquences pour moi. Dans les deux cas, le résultat n'était pas connu d'avance, c'est une surprise. La combinaison avec *bien* sert à renforcer la dénotation négative de *mal*, comme dans l'expression « J'ai bien mal agi ».

Comment: Bonne analyse. On pourrait ajouter que l'emploi du futur antérieur (*aura pris*) dénote un aspect incertain (le locuteur formule une hypothèse), en opposition avec la formulation beaucoup plus définitive qu'aurait induit l'usage du passé composé (*Bien mal m'en a pris*).

Answer (score 7):

*Mal m'en a pris* exprime un regret concernant un action passée, qu'a posteriori on aurait dû éviter de faire.

*Bien m'en a pris* évoque le contraire, qu'après coup, l'intuition qu'on a eu (ou tout simplement le hasard) a fait que l'action passée s'est révélée effectivement bénéfique.

Dans *Bien mal m'en a pris*, *Bien* vient renforcer *mal*, comme un synonyme de *très*.